# how to find cells with "#VALUE!" in EXCEL 2010 VBA

Tags: excel, windows-7, excel-2010, vba

I need to find the max value in a column by EXCEL 2012 VBA. 
Some cells have "#VALUE!". My code does not work.

```
Sub find_max()
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim dblMax As Double
  dblMax = 0
  Set rng = Range("A2:A11")
  For Each cell In rng
     If (cell.Value <> "#VALUE!") Then    // error ! type mismatch
         If dblMax < CDbl(cell.Value) Then
             dblMax = CDbl(cell.Value)
         End If
    End If
 Next cell
 MsgBox dblMax
End Sub
```

I also need to print the cell location (mark it with a color) with the max value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: change `If (cell.Value <> "#VALUE!") Then` to `If NOT ISERROR(cell) Then`

Comment: I also need to print the cell location with the max value. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your range has constants, use

```
application.WorksheetFunction.Max(range("B6:C13").SpecialCells(xlcelltypeconstants,xlNumbers ))
```

if it has formulas, use

```
application.WorksheetFunction.Max(range("B6:C13").SpecialCells(xlcelltypeformulas,xlNumbers ))
```

For the range where it's found, `.Find` should work fine:

```
Sub find_max()


 Dim rng As Range
   Dim dblMax As Double, rgMax As Range

    Set rng = Range("A2:A11")

    dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers))

    Set rgMax = rng.Find(dblMax, , xlValues, xlWhole)

 MsgBox rgMax.Address & ": " & dblMax

End Sub
```

Comment: I got error at dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers). thanks

Comment: If all your numbers are constants, swap that line with `application.WorksheetFunction.Max(range("B6:C13").SpecialCells(xlcelltypeconstants,xlNumbers ))`