# do some calculations for each cell in two aligned columns in EXCEL 2010 by VBA

Tags: vba, excel, windows-7, excel-2010

I need to do some calculations for each cell in two aligned columns in EXCEL 2010 by VBA on Win7.
Write the result in a cell of another column.

My code:

```
   Set result_rng = Range("H2:H10")
   Set aRng = Range("C2:C10")
   Set bRng = Range("F2:F10")
   For Each aCell, bCell, cCell In aRng, bRng, result_rng   // **error here** 
      cEll.Value = Cdl(aCell.Value) - Cdl(b.Cell.Value)
   Next aCell
```

I also need to check wether F column is "NULL", if yes, I will not do calculation and just update a counter.

**update new error of caling a sub**

```
find_max rng1:=rng  // error !!! ByRef argu mismatch 

Sub find_max(ByRef rng1 As Range)
 Dim dblM As Double
 dblM = -9E+307
 Dim maxCellAddress As String
 For Each Cell In rng
    If IsNumeric(c) Then
           If dblMax < CDbl(Cell.Value) And Cell.Value <> "" Then
               dblM = CDbl(Cell.Value)
               maxCellAddress = (Cell.Address)
           End If
    End If
 Next Cell
 End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

Try this one:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = Range("C2:C10")

    For Each c In rng
        If c.Offset(0, 3).Value <> "NULL" Then
            c.Offset(0, 5).Value = c.Value - c.Offset(0, 3).Value
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

where `c.Offset(0, 3)` means offset to the right on 3 columns, i.e. if `c` refers to cell in column `C`, then `c.Offset(0, 3)` gives you corresponding value from column `F` and `c.Offset(0, 5)` gives you corresponding value from column `H`.

If it seems too tricky, you can use this one instead:

```
Range("H" & c.Row).Value = c.Value - Range("F" & c.Row).Value
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
Sub test()
    Dim result_rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim dblM As Double
    Dim maxCellAddress As String

    Set result_rng = Range("H2:H10")

    dblM = -9E+307

    For Each c In result_rng
        If IsNumeric(c) Then
            If dblM < CDbl(c.Value) And c.Value <> "" Then
                dblM = CDbl(c.Value)
                maxCellAddress = c.Address
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I also need to check wether F column is "NULL", if yes, I will not do calculation and just update a counter. Thanks !

Comment: `wether F column is "NULL"` means empty or contains string "NULL"?

Comment: thanks ! I also need to find the max in all non-null cells in column c. But, I gto error. please see the update.

Comment: it seems that it's another question, and you already got answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673373/how-to-find-cells-with-value-in-excel-2010-vba but ok, see my update

Comment: in that post, I got error ("object required") at dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers). thanks

Comment: it's far from original question. Please, if you have additional questions not related to original one, post a new question

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696549/error-of-calling-a-sub-in-excel-2010-in-vba-on-win7 , thanks !