# error of calling a Sub() in EXCEL 2010 in VBA on Win7

Tags: vba, excel, windows-7, excel-2010

i need to call a sub from WEXCEL 2010 VBAon win7.

```
find_max rng1:=rng  // error !!! ByRef argu mismatch 

Sub find_max(ByRef rng1 As Range)

 Dim dblM As Double
 dblM = -9E+307
 Dim maxCellAddress As String
 For Each Cell In rng
 If IsNumeric(c) Then
       If dblMax < CDbl(Cell.Value) And Cell.Value <> "" Then
           dblM = CDbl(Cell.Value)
           maxCellAddress = (Cell.Address)
       End If
 End If
 Next Cell
 End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciate !

Comment: how are you assigning to rng? Is it actually a range? The problem isn't the line where you call find_max. It is where you assign to rng.

Comment: Change `For Each Cell In rng` by `For Each Cell In rng1` to match argument name in `Sub` description.

Comment: @simpLEMAn that is also a problem yeah, but that error would be raised later.

Comment: and `If IsNumeric(c) Then` --> `If IsNumeric(Cell) Then`. Btw, I hope `maxCellAddress` is global variable, because otherwise calling sub `find_max rng1:=rng` doesn't make any sence to me

Comment: Btw you can drop the `ByRef` as it is already the default type of argument passing.

Comment: @simoco another win for `Option Explicit` :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize all of the comments try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:B10")

    Call find_max(rng)
End Sub

Sub find_max(rng1 As Range)
    Dim dblM As Double
    dblM = -9E+307

    Dim maxCellAddress As String
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In rng1
       If IsNumeric(cell) Then
             If dblM < CDbl(cell.Value) And cell.Value <> "" Then
                 dblM = CDbl(cell.Value)
                 maxCellAddress = (cell.Address)
             End If
       End If
    Next cell

    MsgBox (maxCellAddress)
End Sub
```

---

If you want to return the max cell value change it to a function like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:B10")

    MsgBox (find_max(rng))
End Sub

Function find_max(rng1 As Range)
    Dim dblM As Double
    dblM = -9E+307

    Dim maxCellAddress As String
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In rng1
       If IsNumeric(cell) Then
             If dblM < CDbl(cell.Value) And cell.Value <> "" Then
                 dblM = CDbl(cell.Value)
                 maxCellAddress = (cell.Address)
             End If
       End If
    Next cell

    find_max = maxCellAddress
End Function
```

Comment: I think `dblMax` should be `dblM`

Comment: @simoco yeah, there are still a few things that don't line up... such as what happens to maxCellAddress variable?

Comment: my opinion is that it should be `Function find_max(rng1 As Range) As String` and return `maxCellAddress`. But we should wait until OP clarify their intensions